# How to auto on-board EC2 instances in an autoscaling group?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

Currently, I have a CFN template to creates an auto-scaling group, which launches instances based on a launch template. I would like to onboard with Systems Manager to automate patching, but I can only find the UI (Quick Setup) and not CFN for performing all those actions; I want to make sure any new instances spun up in the auto-scaling group will be onboarded with SSM as well and become managed instances. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: For this you only need IAM role to add to your instances. SSM is already installed and running in the standard AMIs.

Comment: I see - I know the SSM Agent is installed and running, but I also see an onboarding processing in the UI (the "Quick Start") where it do numerous setup things; how do I ensure those step things are done for new instances?

Comment: These things are only done once for your account. Not for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are few prerequisites.
You can refer this : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/systems-manager-ec2-instance-not-appear/

In short, ssm agent must be running and must be able to reach ssm endpoints (public or vpc endpoints) and must have necessary permission in instance profile to make API calls to SSM service, in order to register the instance.